# Angular - Argument of type '"baseStore"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"conectado" | "vista"'

Tags: angular

Recientemente tome un proyecto en la empresa en la que estoy actualmente trabajando, en la cual, necesito correr el sistema en Angular pero cuando coloco el comando `ng serve`, me aparece el error mostrado en el titulo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No entiendo que intenta hacer la persona que hizo este código, alguien podría explicarme a que se debe el problema y como solucionarlo?

Comment: Agrega el código de `Store`. Y es mejor el código como texto en lugar de imagen.

Comment: Pero sobre todo, añade el código como texto, no como imagen

Comment: Gracias Lobos por tu respuesta, sin embargo, hago lo que dices y aun asi no funciona

Comment: podrias añadir el codigo dentro de Store?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está pasando es que se está utilizando una librería para manejar el estado de la aplicación.

Store es parte de NGRX y puedes aprender más de eso aquí: https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Pero básicamente el `select` de store solo puede ser llamado con `conectado` o `vista`; ya que esos son las únicas opciones en el BaseStore
Una solución podría ser:

```js
baseStore.select('conectado').subscribe(conectado => {
   this.conectado = conectado;
});
```